# RxJava- Placing several Observable values in a static body of text?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have heard several reactive programming folks say "don't break the monad, just continue it". I see the merit in this. There are still certain instances I'm confused about, especially when the `Observable` is finally consumed or subscribed to. This is even more confusing when several observables have to be consumed at once, and it doesn't feel very practical to combine them into a single observable.

Let's say for instance I have a `TrackedAircraft` type. Some of its properties are final while other properties are `Observable`.

```
public interface TrackedAircraft {

    public int getFlightNumber();
    public int getCapacity();
    public Observable<String> getOrigin();
    public Observable<String> getDestination();
    public Observable<Integer> getMileage();
    public Observable<Point> getLocation();

}
```

I could wire this to a GUI pretty easily, and just subscribe controls to be updated with each emission of each property. But what about an email or a body of static text? This is not as straightforward because the only way I can think of not breaking the monad is to combine all the observables which sounds like a pain especially if I have an Observable emitting TrackedFlights.

Is it okay to block in this situation? Or is there a more monadic way to accomplish this I haven't thought of?

```
public static String generateEmailReportForFlight(TrackedAircraft flight) { 
    return new StringBuilder().append("FLIGHT NUMBER: ").append(flight.getFlightNumber()).append("\r\n")
    .append("CAPACITY: ").append(flight.getCapacity()).append("\r\n")
    .append("ORIGIN: ").append(flight.getOrigin() /*What do I do here without blocking?*/)
    .append("DESTINATION: ").append(flight.getDestination() /*What do I do here without blocking?*/)
    .append("MILEAGE: ").append(flight.getMileage() /*What do I do here without blocking?*/)
    .append("LOCATION: ").append(flight.getLocation() /*What do I do here without blocking?*/)
    .toString();
}
```

///

```
Observable<TrackedAircraft> trackedFlights = ...;
trackedFlights.map(f -> generateEmailReportForFlight(f));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap + combineLatest:

```
Observable<TrackedAircraft> trackedFlights = ...

trackedFlights
.flatMap(flight -> emailReport(flight))
.subscribe(msg -> sendEmail(msg));

Observable<String> emailReport(TrackedAircraft flight) {
    return Observable.combineLatest(
        flight.getOrigin(), 
        flight.getDestination(), 
        flight.getMileage(), 
        flight.getLocation()
        (origin, destination, mileage, location) -> {
             return new StringBuilder()
             .append("FLIGHT NUMBER: ").append(flight.getFlightNumber())
             .append("\r\n")
             .append("CAPACITY: ").append(flight.getCapacity())
             .append("\r\n")
             .append("ORIGIN: ").append(origin)
             .append("\r\n")
             .append("DESTINATION: ").append(destination)
             .append("\r\n")
             .append("MILEAGE: ").append(mileage)
             .append("\r\n")
             .append("LOCATION: ").append(location)
             .toString();
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I was kind of thinking of combineLatest(), but thought it would be tedious. Actually this is not that bad in combination with the flatMap(). Thanks!